# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 using Array in

Tags: php

Not sure how to fix this error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\streams.php on line 50
>        Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\streams.php on line 53
>        Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\streams.php on line 54

Code its referring to:

```
<?php

$members = array("hawkmyg");

$userGrab = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=";

$checkedOnline = array (); 

foreach($members as $i =>$value){
    $userGrab .= ",";
    $userGrab .= $value;
}
unset($value);

//grabs the channel data from twitch.tv streams
$json_file = file_get_contents($userGrab, 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

//get's member names from stream url's and checks for online members
foreach($members as $i =>$value){
    $title = $json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url'];
    $array = explode('/', $title);
    $member = end($array);
    $viewer = $json_array[$i] ['stream_count'];
    onlinecheck($member, $viewer);
    $checkedOnline[] = signin($member);
}
```

Cannot figure out how to fix

Comment: Without seeing your input data (`$members` and `$json_array`) nobody can help you. But I'd expect `$i == 0` during the first loop and `$json_array` not having an element `0`.

Comment: use standard debugging tools `var_dump` or `print_r`

Comment: uset print_r to see if the offset 0 really exist

Comment: Ok added more to the code hope that is what is needed

Comment: no, some effort from you is needed. at least read the comments.

Comment: Array ( [0] => hawkmyg ) array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "hawkmyg" }

Comment: lovely. you already knew what that array contained... how's that going to help?

Answer (score 0):

The notice of an undefined offset occurs when one calls an array element with the specific index, for example, `echo $array[$index]`, but the index is not defined within the array.

In your code, the array `$members` has one element (with index `0`). So we're walking exactly one time through your foreach loop.
You're calling `$json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url']` where `$i = 0`, but `$json_array[0]` does not exist.

You should check the contents of `$json_array` using `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

I tested the script myself, and when I read the contents of the link http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=,hawkmyg, it returned an empty JSON array. The channel 'hawkmyg' does not exist.
I tried the channel 'hatoyatv', and it just worked.

Comment: I know what it is now, I dont have justin.tv account only twitch.tv and the api is different ty Emperor